# How many partitions of 12 that fit the requirements?

Tags: integer-partitions

How many partitions of $12$ are there that have at least four parts, such that the largest, second-largest, third-largest, and fourth-largest parts are respectively greater than or equal to $4,3,2,1$?

For example, $12=4+4+2+2$ works.

Comment: There aren't that many. Simply listing them out works. Have you tried that?

Comment: Oh yeah, I've got this problem but I wanted to know if there was a different way.

Comment: OK, is $\binom52+1+1=12$ the right answer?

Comment: Yes! How did you get that expression?

Comment: $\binom52$ ways to increase two of the five "piles" $4,3,2,1,0$ by $1$, plus two solutions that can't be obtained in this way, namely $6+3+2+1$ and $4+3+2+1+1+1$.